# Unable to get success message when user guess right number when prompted to guess number between 0 to 9

Tags: python-3.x

Help out me please... new to python
I am finding my way to program in Python 3.7 where in system asks user to guess the number which should match with already defined number:

**

```
num=9
inp=input("Please guess any number between 0 to 9:    ")
if inp==num:
    print("Well Guessed.!")
else:
    while inp!=num:
        print("Please try again")
        inp=input("Please guess any number between 0 to 9:    ")
```

**

Unfortunately i am unable to get success message.

kindly help

Comment: `input` always returns a string. You're comparing it to an integer, so you'll never get a value of `True`. `'1'!=1`

Answer (score 0):

As @Ed Ward said, you are comparing a string and an integer. You need to convert the `inp` to int, first. Let's also use a try/catch to avoid bad input.

```
try:
   val = int(inp)
except ValueError:
   print("Input is not an int.")
```

Here is the way to use it:

```
num=9
inp=input("Please guess any number between 0 to 9:    ")
try:
    val = int(inp)
except ValueError:
    print("Input is not an int.")
if val==num:
    print("Well Guessed.!")
else:
    while val!=num:
        print("Please try again")
        inp=input("Please guess any number between 0 to 9:    ")
        try:
            val = int(inp)
        except ValueError:
            print("Input is not an int.")
```